# Have created a click effect for a single image, but would like to have the other images have the same effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image

I'm at a point where I've tried every other option, but I can't seem to solve this problem. Here's an explanation of the experience:

When visiting the page, the person is introduced to a number of images (tagged with classes, for example two of the images are tagged `img01` and `img02`). When an image is clicked, the image maintains it's place (`img01`'s z-index is risen) while all the other images fade away (DIV with a white fill fades in and covers `img02`), and a text that explains the piece fades in as well (DIV tagged `object-text` with `img01`'s supporting text fades in).

While I got the `img01` functionality to work, I can't seem to do the same for `img02`. I'm also planning on adding more tags (such as `img03` and `img04`) and am wondering if there is a smarter, more effective way this can be structured.

For functionality reference, here's a http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nvwzgus0/4/
Below, is the html, css, and the java code.

Thanks in advance!

**html**

```
<a href="#" id="object" class="img01"> <img class="img01" src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcepyv1Qfv1ru82ue.jpg"/></a>
<div id="object-text" class="img01">
    <h1>img01 Text<br/>img01 Text</h1>
</div>

<a href="#" id="object" class="img02"> <img class="img02" src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcepyv1Qfv1ru82ue.jpg"/></a>
<div id="object-text" class="img02">
    <h1>img02 Text<br/>img02 Text</h1>
</div>

<div id="filler"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#object {
    top: 100px;
    left:100px;
}
#object-text {
    display:none;
    z-index:100000;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#filler {
    display:none;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: white;
    z-index:1000;
    opacity: 0.8;
}
h1 {
    font-size:20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    color: red;
}

.img01, .img02 {
    position:absolute;
}
.img01 img, .img02 img {
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
}
.img01 {
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
}
.img02 {
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#object").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$("#object").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("#object").css("z-index", "2000");
    $("#object-text").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#filler").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#inner").css("z-index", "2000");
});

$(document).click(function () {
    $("#filler").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#object-text").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues with your code.  You should be using unique ID's for each DOM element, and targeting your images by class name.  I've made a few changes to your example and restructured it slightly to show you a better approach.

http://jsfiddle.net/nvwzgus0/6/

Wrapped each image in a containing tag, removed duplicate ID's and using class names instead

```
<a href="#" class="img img01">
    <img class="img01" src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcepyv1Qfv1ru82ue.jpg"/>
    <div class="object-text">
        <h1>img01 Text<br/>img01 Text</h1>
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#" class="img img02">
    <img class="img02" src="http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_mcepyv1Qfv1ru82ue.jpg"/>
    <div class="object-text">
        <h1>img02 Text<br/>img02 Text</h1>
    </div>
</a>

<div id="filler"></div>
```

Added CSS class for changing z-index instead of setting it manually, to make it easier to toggle on and off.

```
a.top {
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Modified event handling to target new containing tag:

```
$("a.img").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(this).addClass("top");
    $(this).find(".object-text").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#filler").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Modified how images z-index is reset:

```
$(document).click(function () {
    $("#filler").fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $("a.img").removeClass("top");
    });
    $(".object-text").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

Comment: — I'm just blown away how you were able to simplify it to that extent—Bravo! However, I do have a minor issue I've noticed — When an image is clicked, for a brief second the type goes behind the image and goes back in front. Is there any way to fix it? Also, how might I be able to fade out the `#filler` by clicking the image, too? Thank you, you're awesome!

Comment: @kenhimself The issue with the type going behind the image is related to the z-index being set only after the fade completes. I'm assuming that you won't actually have text in your final design making this a non-issue, but there's more info on how to fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055269/jquery-fadein-on-positionabsolute-causes-z-index-issue.  Fading out the filler when the image is clicked is fairly simple. I've updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nvwzgus0/8/.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I think I implemented the solution that was suggested on the post you provided me with correctly, but it seems to be working now. http://jsfiddle.net/kenhimself/nvwzgus0/9/

Comment: You got it @Mun. Again, thanks for the help. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem I see here is that you have two objects with the same id.  Change this, and your code should work.  I would recommend switching what you have as ids (object)  to classes, and what you have as classes (img02 and img01) to ids.

I looked over your code some more and it seems you are doing this a lot.  Make sure that when you code you NEVER reuse ids...like ever. Both your a's and your divs have duplicate ids....

Not to be mean, but this does need a lot of work.  Feel free to ask any questions if you need more help.

Comment: thanks for the advice! I'm still new to java / css3 / html5. I never knew duplicating ids are never a good idea—and you're right, it does make it A LOT simpler when it's only used once. I support I should start training myself to think like a proper developer :)