# Bootstrap active tab is seen through overlay background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Bootstrap and Bootstrap tabs. I am fading in a custom overlay background and for some reason, the active tab goes through the background during the transition. I can't figure this one out.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1033xzyt/17/)

HTML

```
<div id="container" style="display:none;">
  <div id="bg">
  </div>
</div>

<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#home" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#profile" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#messages" aria-controls="messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#settings" aria-controls="settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#bg {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.50);
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 2000;
}

* {
  transition: all 250ms;
}
```

JS

```
$('#container').fadeIn();
```

Comment: what do you want to get?  explain clearly your issue, please!

Comment: Like I said, " the active tab goes through the background during the transition" - this shouldn't happen. You an see in the fiddle that it is very messed up.

Comment: but `z-index: 2000` for `#bg` is this property neсessary?

Comment: Yes. I just need to understand why a simple tab is messing with a simple backdrop.

Comment: if you fadeIn the #bg instead of the #container it solves the issue..
But the issue itself I think it is related to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055269/jquery-fadein-on-positionabsolute-causes-z-index-issue FadeIn changes the Z-Index

Answer (score -1):

change

```
#bg {z-index: 2000;}
```

to

```
#bg {z-index: 0;}
```

OR

```
.nav-tabs>li {
z-index: 2001;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I meant I don't want the active tab to glitch out like it does. The active tabs should behave like the other ones.

Comment: Ok, then i think we have to override css by .nav-tabs>li.active>a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover{
    cursor: default;
    background-color: inherit;
    border: inherit;
}