# Chrome z index when animating slide in menu

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome

I am trying to create a slide in menu similar to the sidenav of https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview except have it be fixed to the window so it can be opened anywhere.

The linked plnkr works correctly when run in the plnkr window. But running the same code locally does not work correctly.
https://plnkr.co/edit/f5zOlcf9hxlHZeu0BQiL

The slide in menu is correctly positioned on top of the rest of the page with the background over all other content. But when running locally in chrome, the menu and background overlay only come to the front once the animation is complete.

[image: chrome]
[image: firstfox]

It looks like the elements being relatively positioned causes the issue. When using a simple flex layout and not using bootstrap, the elements appear correctly in chrome. A div around the slider template seems to correct the issue in chrome but not sure why.

```
   <div>
        <div class="slider__content"
             [class.slider--show-backdrop]="open">
            <div>Header</div>
        </div>

        <div class="slider-backdrop"
             [class.slider--show-backdrop]="open"
             (click)="close()">
        </div>
      </div>
```

Some resources I have found are [jQuery fadeIn on position:absolute causes z-index issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7055269/jquery-fadein-on-positionabsolute-causes-z-index-issue) and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context.

Is this a bug in chrome or something I am not understanding with animations and z-index?